# Are setters atomic in .Net?

Tags: .net, concurrency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are reads and writes to properties atomic in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151873/are-reads-and-writes-to-properties-atomic-in-c)

Are the auto-generated setters atomic in .NET 4?

```
Public property Busy As boolean
```

Comment: What do you mean with "atomic"? An assignment can either happen or not. There is nothing inbetween.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Some assignments are atomic, others not. Assigning a `Decimal` for example isn't atomic, simply because the data (128 bits) is larger than the data bus (32/64 bits).

Comment: @Guffa: So I could end up with a decimal that has some bits from the value before the assignment and some bits from the value I wanted to assign? Meaning I would have a decimal with a represented value that is not the old and not the new value?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, no.  That's just silly

Comment: @smartcaveman: Why do you say that? Guffa's comment implied exactly that.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, Check Jon Skeet's answer on the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @smartcaveman: This answer doesn't change my understanding: An assignment to a decimal is not atomic and after the first 32 bits were written, a thread switch could occur and another thread gets the partly changed value.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yes, that is right. If you read a non-atomic value that is changed by another thread, without any synchronisation to protect it, you may get a partially written value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not guaranteed to be.

Consider that the above compiles to a full form property with a backing field. A different thread may come in between the setter invocation and the actual assignment of the backing field.

Also, not all types can be assigned atomically - large value types (`DateTime`, `TimeSpan` etc...) are too large for an atomic assignment.

Comment: In Objetive-c accessors are atomic. What use have accessors in C# compared to declaring the variable public?

Comment: Indirection/encapsulation is why they exist

Answer (score 1):

No.  A setter is a method with special syntax.  Auto-Properties are properties with automatically generated getters and setters.  The compiler generates an underlying field that is retrieved by the getter method and assigned by the setter method.

For example,

```
 public bool Property { get; set; }
```

is actually compiled into something like:

```
private bool underlyingField;

public bool Property { 
   get { 
      return underlyingField;
   } 
   set { 
      underlyingField = value;
   }
}
```

A field may be considered an atomic unit, and writing to a field is an atomic operation.

Comment: Comment why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a property assignment is atomic if the assignment of the type itself is atomic.

The setter is a method so the assignment is wrapped in a method call (if it's not inlined), but the actual assignment that it does is atomic.