# Does a simple property need synchronization?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, synchronization

I have a simple property:

```
Private _t As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Public Property Test As DateTime
        Get
            Return _t
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            _t = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Now I have two independent threads: Thread one permanently invokes the getter and thread two permanently invokes the setter with datetime.now

Do I need to sync the property? **Can the property be in an undefined or null/nothing state or will it alway return a date?**

Comment: See the second answer in the duplicate.

Comment: There are tons of duplicates. Here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7161413/993547. And maybe even better duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1151873/993547.